# Can't get my contact form to work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have a question about creating a contact form. Currently I have a form and some php code. But every time when I click on the submit button, I will be redirected to the php site itself instead of sending an actual mail.

This is the code I have:

HTML Form:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post" target="_new">
  <h1>Name:</h1> <br><input type="text" name="name" class="name"><br>
  <h1>E-mail:</h1> <br><input type="text" name="email" class="email"><br>
  <h1>Message:</h1> <br><textarea rows="20" cols="60" width="450px" height="210px" name="message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

Php page:

```
<?php

$recipient = "myemail@mail.com";
if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    mail("$recipient", $name, $message);
}
header('Location: send.php');
?>
```

I've read on the internet that there is a possibility with Ajax and javascript? But I'm not very familiar with AJAX. So help would be really appreciated! :D

The only thing this form has to do is to send an email to my email account without opening a mail program while clicking on the submit button.

Thanks in regard!

Comment: is the form is in the page `send.php`

Comment: Yup, checked that countless times.  :)

Comment: I would rather do a check on `$_POST['submit']` than see if the email is set or not, but that is personal preference.

Comment: Whatever the problem with sending the email is, adding Ajax to the mix won't help solve it.

Comment: I don't understand your code if both the form and the php are on send.php why is there a header('Location: send.php');??? if the php code isn't on send.php then changing the action="send.php" to action="wherever_the_php_code_is" will most probably solve your issue.

Comment: No the form is on my index.html and the php on send.php ;)

Comment: ok where are you trying this code on a server online or on your localhost? and as stated below you should change your header("Location: send.php"); to something else

Answer (score 0):

When you clicking on submit button, the action is gone to `send.php` after the mail function irt is redirected to `send.php` itself. So a selfloop starts. You need to change that
 redirect page to your form page. ie.,

```
header('Location: send.php'); //change it !!
```

Also you need a `mail server` to send the mail from the local machine otherwise you need to host the project.

If you want to send the mail using `AJAX` does the following code:

```
<script>
$('form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'send.php',
        data:$('form').serialize(),
        success:function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Then **send.php** will be like

```
$recipient = "myemail@mail.com";
if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $mail = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if(mail($recipient, $name, $message)){
        echo 'Mail sent';
    }
    else{
         echo 'Mail cant sent';
    }
}
```

Comment: What exacly do you mean with mail server? You mean an actual email? Cause in my code I use my own email but dont want to put it on here ;)

But I changed the location to the index and now it doesn't go to the php page anymore. Next thing is receiving the email. Haven't received one jet :/

Comment: At the moment yes. But I can upload it to my host if needed.

Comment: OKay..the `mail()` function is only working if you installed a mail sever in your local machine. dats y you didnt get a mail....test it in your remote server

Comment: Ye! I got a mail! Great! :D

Last question. When I click on submit I'll be redirected to the php page. To stay on my own index.html do I have to use the header()?

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove the double quote "" in $recipient

```
mail($recipient, $name, $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form  method="post">
                            <h1>Name:</h1> <br><input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="name"><br>
                            <h1>E-mail:</h1> <br><input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="email"><br>
                            <h1>Message:</h1> <br><textarea id="msg" rows="20" cols="60" width="450px" height="210px" name="message"></textarea><br>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit">
                        </form>
<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "send.php",
    data: {name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val(), message: $('#msg').val()},
    success: function(result){
        alert("Mail send!");
    }
});
</script>
```

your php code is the same but you don't need the header.